# In the regular wreath product $W = H \wr G$, every subgroup of $G$ is the centralizer of some element

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, wreath-product

This is Exercise 3A.9 - (b) from M. Isaacs' "Finite Group Theory". It goes as follows:

> Let $W = H \wr G$ be the regular wreath product and let $C \leq G$ be an arbitrary subgroup. Show that there exists some $b \in B$, where $B = \{f:G \to H\}$ is the base group of $W$, such that $C = C_G(b)$

As far as I understand, an element of $G$ centralizes an arbitrary function $b \in B$ if and only if $b(g^{-1}k) = b(k), \forall k \in G$, since conjugation by an element of $G$ amounts to applying the action of that element; i.e: $$g^{-1}bg = g \cdot b$$

I tried to get some intuition, so I assumed first that $H = 1$. In particular, there is only one function from $G$ to $H$: everyone gets mapped to $1$. But this means *every* element of $G$ centralizes every element of $B$ (because there is only one), so it seems the result cannot possibly be true... What did I get wrong?

Nowhere were the actions required to be faithful, so I don't see what's wrong with picking a trivial example such as this one...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect that Isaacs is thinking of a nontrivial wreath product (the wreath product $\{e\}\wr G$ is just $G$, after all).

Comment: Yes, you need to assume that the group $H$ is nontrivial. If you do that then the result is correct. The idea is that, choose some $ t \in H \setminus\{1\}$ and then define $b$ by letting $f(g) = t$ for $g \in H$ and $f(g) = 1$ for $g \in G \setminus H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, when you use “$H$” in the second instance, do you mean the subgroup $C$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant let $f(g)=t$ for $g \in  C$ and $f(g)=1$ for $g \in G \setminus C$.